# Use Bash to sort vector into numbers, then letters

Tags: bash, sorting

Say I have a file which contains the following column:

M
2
10
X

Is it possible to sort based on this column to obtain:

2
10
M
X

I have tried using -g and -n but those output letters first, then numbers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How often are you going to do this, and how big are the data files you'll do it on?  If it's "once" and "small", then you've got a decent enough answer from Anubhava.  If it's "many times" and "humungous", then you could still use that technique, or you could devise a program that creates a good sort key at the start of each line (say `0` for numbers and `1` for letters), followed by the rest of the line. You can then use `sort -k1,1 -k2n,2` and finally strip off the added prefix. `sed -e '/^[0-9]/s/^/0 /' -e '/^[^0-9]/s/^/1 /' files... | sort -k1,1 -k2n,2 | sed 's/^[01] //'` or thereabouts.

Comment: many times, humongous files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably sort won't have this support. I can only think of this *cheat mode*:

```
sort -n <(awk '/^[0-9]+$/' file) && sort <(awk '!/^[0-9]+$/' file)
2
10
M
X
```

Answer (score 2):

version sorting seems to do what you want;

```
sort -V <<END
M
2
10
X
END
```

```
2
10
M
X
```

may require GNU sort

Answer (score 0):

You can sort it once by letter, then sort it by number. So...

```
sort test.txt -o test.txt && sort -n test.txt -o test.txt
```

Comment: Are you sure? The `sort -n` will place the letters first because they are mapped to zero. The first sort will place the numbers first, but in codeset order, not numeric order.

Comment: I did not test the two commands appended together, but I did test them one right after the other. That is probably the issue. Now I think I recall learning that && executes at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty long, but:

```
re='^[0-9]+$'; 
while read line; 
do 
   if ! [[ $line =~ $re ]]
   then 
        printf "%d,A\n" "'$line"
   else 
        printf "%d,N\n" "$line"
   fi
done < file | sort -t ',' -k1n | awk -v FS=',' '{ if($2=="N"){print $1} else {printf "%c\n",$1}}'
```